# How to merge two tables with different column sizes with no space between them

Tags: tables, spacing, tabularray

I try to put tables from the `tabularray` package together but without changing the Sizes of the table. In the End it should look like this:

[image]

My idea to accomplish this is by creating two different tables with and try to change the spacing between them, but I have no idea how to do this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{X[l,1]X[l,2]X[l,3]}
    \hline
    Name & Geb & Lebensgeschichte \\ 
    \hline
    Jens & 146 & Ich bin the Best\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\begin{tblr}{X[l,2]X[l,1]X[l,2]}
    \hline
    Name & Geb & Lebensgeschichte \\ 
    \hline
    Jens & 146 & Ich bin the Best\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Result, but with the space between the two tables:

[image]

Thanks for your time.
Jens Seyfarth

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (a bit rude solution, but works):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\noindent%
\begin{tblr}{hlines,
             colspec = {X[l,1]X[l,2]X[l,3]}
             }
    Name & Geb & Lebensgeschichte \\
    Jens & 146 & Ich bin the Best\\
\end{tblr}
\begin{tblr}{hline{2-Z},
             colspec = {X[l,1]X[l,2]X[l,3]},
             row{1}  = {abovesep=0pt},
             }
    Name & Geb & Lebensgeschichte \\
    Jens & 146 & Ich bin the Best\\
\end{tblr}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

The trick is that in the second table you not draw first `\hline` and reduce space above the first row to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move the other table to the next paragraph. Next, LaTeX will adds a small gap between paragraphs if a box containing such paragraph exceeds a regular height. This happens if you insert anything of size larger than standard text, s.a. table, image or so. Size of that gap is controlled by `\lineskip`. However, you can simply tell LaTeX not to add anything before the very next paragraph if you insert `\nointerlineskip`. In your case, you should add it before the second table.

Here's the code. Obviously, you may want to remove top `\hline` in the second table depending on the final effect.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{center}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}%
\begin{tblr}{X[l,1]X[l,2]X[l,3]}
    \hline
    Name & Geb & Lebensgeschichte \\ 
    \hline
    Jens & 146 & Ich bin the Best\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\nointerlineskip   % removes \lineskip
\begin{tblr}{X[l,2]X[l,1]X[l,2]}
    \hline
    Name & Geb & Lebensgeschichte \\ 
    \hline
    Jens & 146 & Ich bin the Best\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]